# Make dynamic favicon of IOS Chrome web share

Tags: ios, google-chrome, favicon

The location of the favicon is clicking the share button at right top hand corner in iOS's Chrome. The icon is in the share drawer which I circle it out in the picture below.

When I make it as a dynamic icon base on the url, I leave the href empty at the beginning in index.html and add the path of the icon to the href in js or a script to the href. `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="" />` As a result, it doesn't work to make it dynamic. What I guess is seem like chrome only set the icon at the beginning. Because I leave it empty in index.html, there is no icon. The change I add later doesn't have any effect on the icon.

But if I hard code the path in index.html, e.g `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />`. The icon shows up. However, if I want to change href path to something else by script, it doesn't have any effect as well.

Is there any way that can make this icon dynamic? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know browser gets icon from inside url metatag. So if it is no favicon there located it will render empty icon.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean here. Can you detail your answer?